# Should the minimum signed 64-bit integer when represented as a BigDecimal round-trip cleanly through Double?

Tags: java

I have some code that expects that `BigDecimal` values that have an exact representation as a `Double` will round-trip cleanly. That is, if I take that `BigDecimal`, convert it to a `Double`, and convert the result back to a `BigDecimal`, the result will compare equal to the original.

However, the following test case fails with the message `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <0> but was: <192>` in openjdk 11.0.19 2023-04-18 LTS.

```java
  @Test
  void checkThatMin64BitIntegerAsBigDecimalRoundTripsThroughDouble() {
    final var min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(
      "-9223372036854775808"
    );
    final var min64BitIntegerAsDouble = min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimal.doubleValue();
    final var min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimalAgain = BigDecimal.valueOf(
      min64BitIntegerAsDouble
    );
    assertEquals(
      BigDecimal.ZERO,
      min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimal.subtract(min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimalAgain)
    );
  }
```

[image: -2^63] is -1 times a power of 2 with a small enough exponent that [it has an exact representation as a double](https://float.exposed/0xc3e0000000000000). So, I'd expect it to round-trip cleanly. What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Use `new BigDecimal(double_value)` instead of `BigDecimal.valueOf(Double)` if you care about accuracy. The API note is not talking about you.

## Details

(I'm answering my own question because I discovered the answer as I finished writing the question. But I didn't see a good answer on StackOverflow.)

Because the difference between the converted value and the original value is 192, that makes the value after passing through double -9223372036854776000. This implies that they are converting the string "-9.223372036854776E18" or something like it.

This is precisely what [the docs for `BigDecimal.valueOf(Double)` in Java 11 specify](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double))

> Translates a double into a `BigDecimal`, using the double's canonical string representation provided by the `Double.toString(double)` method.

The API note on `BigDecimal.valueOf(Double)` says

> This is generally the preferred way to convert a double (or float) into a `BigDecima`l, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a `BigDecimal` from the result of using `Double.toString(double)`.

However, that conversion loses information. If you use `new BigDecimal(double_value)` instead, it will round-trip successfully. The following succeeds.

```java
  @Test
  void checkThatMin64BitIntegerAsBigDecimalRoundTripsThroughDouble() {
    final var min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(
      "-9223372036854775808"
    );
    final var min64BitIntegerAsDouble = min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimal.doubleValue();
    final var min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimalAgain = new BigDecimal(
      min64BitIntegerAsDouble
    );
    assertEquals(
      BigDecimal.ZERO,
      min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimal.subtract(min64BitIntegerAsBigDecimalAgain)
    );
  }
```

Comment: `BigDecimal.valueOf` was designed for people making the opposite mistake: people who expect `(double) 0.1` to become the `BigDecimal` 0.1, even though those have different values as real numbers.